# Is it possible to program an Arduino in other languages?

Tags: arduino, programming

Is it possible to program an Arduino with other languages that aren't C/C++ based? What would be required to do so? I know that other IDE's are available, I'm curious about actual programming languages, like being able to code the Arduino in Python, as an example.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify that I'm talking about languages, not the IDE.

Comment: If C# is your thing, check out the Netduino.

Comment: @KevinMark There is the slight issue that he might not be able to use a Netduino (needs the added ports of a Mega, for example).

Comment: @Polar I believe the Netduino Go has additional connectivity options.

Comment: Are the Arduino specific objects like `String` replaceable by C stuff?

Comment: @powtac String is Arduino specific? I wonder why I have so many in my code then...

Comment: @Polar See http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject as far as I understand it is not compatible with other String types. I once tried to use other methods on a String object and then found out that they don't work.

Comment: @powtac You could just write a wrapper for String in C/C++ to get the same functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely possible to use alternate languages for development with Arduino, just not necessarily using the standard IDE. This is as, at the end of the day, the C/C++ code is assembled into byte-code for the AT-chip on the Arduino board. One language you could use is [Céu](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,90129.0.html), a higher-level version of C/C++. The main issue that you'll have is finding a compiler for your language of choice - at the end of the day, you could write your own - however, this requires an intimate jnowledge of C/C++ anyways. Therefore, it is probably best to stick to C/C++, at least for the time being.

EDIT: You've slightly rephrased your question, so yes, it would be possible to program your Arduino in Python (poor choice of language, though that's just my opinion), but you would need a different IDE / a custom compiler for the reasons above. Also, you would have to be careful when linking libraries written in a different language for the Arduino (as they're all C/C++).

Comment: It really is *not* possible to run python on the arduino (except the Arduino Mega, anyways). The [python-on-a-chip](http://code.google.com/p/python-on-a-chip/) project is working on a compact python runtime, and it needs at least ~8KB of SRAM.

Comment: Python is really, **really** not suited for small, memory-constrained environments.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Two points: 1) My use of Python as an example was as it was in the question - I dislike Python anyways. 2) Theoretically, you could convert the Python into C and then you would avoid the need for a Python runtime _on top_ of the bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there *currently* isn't any way to easily code an Arduino in anything but Assembly/C/C++ (and [Céu](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,90129.0.html) as mentioned in Polar's answer -- though this is just translated into C++). There are many languages from which you can [communicate with the arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Interfacing), though.

However, in *theory* it is not impossible. You just need to write a compiler for the chip and define the built-in functions, and then transmit the compiled code via the serial port. Or you can write a python-to-c++ translator and get that to work.

If you have a penchant for .NET, you may want to check out the [Netduino](http://netduino.com/). There seems to be a Java runtime environment for the AVR as well, called the [NanoVM](http://www.harbaum.org/till/nanovm/index.shtml). There's also [dk-basic](https://code.google.com/p/dk-basic/) for BASIC. I've not tried any of these, though.